# Why does VoLTE deployment only take a "Carrier Update" on iOS for all iPhones to have it enabled, but only a select few Android handsets get it?

Tags: calls, 4g, carriers

I am guessing carriers need to adjust the software, but why isn't this negotiated by Android by default so that no modifications would be necessary? Why is there no equivalent of "carrier updates"?

Comment: Because for a carrier it is easier to update 2 or 3 iPhones types compared to 20-100 Android device types (only considering the most common types). Anyway Android has also "carrier updates" - a branded firmware allows the carrier to adapt the software as well. However only a few carrier world-wide really do so, they usually just add apps and themes or disable certain features.

Comment: Because the carrier needs iPhone more than it needs Android. Part of the deal with Android is that there's no one real bargaining unit for the overarching ecosystem. With iPhone, one company is solely responsible for the hardware and the software.